# Regex match all lines that don't end with ,0 and ,1

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a malformed CSV file which has two columns: Text,Value

The value is either 1 or 0, but some lines are malformed and span two lines:

```
1. "This line is fine, but there are some that are not like this",0
2. "Another good line",1
4. "Oh, I'm so bad!!
5. I spanned two lines!",0
6. "Why did you break me? FileHelpers can't read two lines!!",1
```

Line 4 and 5 are supposed to be one line, but the CSV file I got is broken and they span two lines, this causes the FileHelpers engine to fail while reading the csv file.

I have two CSV files with about 3000 lines each and I will only need to fix them once. I want to use notepad++ to find all the lines that are not ending in ,0 or ,1, what kind of regex can I use for that? Or maybe to regular expressions, one for the ,0 case the other one for the ,1 case.

**Update:**
Dan's answer works without the comma [^01]$ instead of ,[^01]$, but it only matches lines that are not ending with 0 or 1... it works sufficiently well in my case, but it does skip lines that are broken and actually end with 0 or 1.

Comment: That's not malformed; quoted fields in CSV files are allowed to contain newlines.  Whatever you're using to read the file is what's broken.

Comment: I'm using [FileHelpers](http://www.filehelpers.com/) and sure, it's not necessarily malformed but you get the point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how the other answer would work:

Something like the below is what I would use in Notepad++

```
[^,][^01]$
```

Here are the steps I did:

Use `([^,][^01])$` to match the lines and replaced with `\1{marked}`

Then switched to extended mode and replaced `{marked}\r\n` with `` ( empty ) to get a single line.

Screenshots below:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I didn't use the comma from the answer, Dan posted just [^01]$ and then he edited it to ,[^01]$... the strange thing is that the edit is not showing

Answer (score 2):

`,[^01]$`

Make sure regex mode is on.

Comment: How can this work? That regex finds all lines that end in a comma followed by not-a-0-or-1. It does not match anything in the example file you gave, Lirik.

Comment: @Christian Semrau: Read the question.

Comment: @BoltClock: I did. And I understand that, in the example file given in the question, line 4 is searched for. The regex given by Dan Breen does not match that line.

Comment: And the `, ` in first line and other lines would match as well

Comment: @Christian True, this won't match line 4. I was focused more on his statement about it finding lines not ending with ",0" or ",1". This is a one-off question for a pretty specific purpose. It worked for OP and I doubt this question will ever be used by anyone for reference... but +1 to your answer anyway for extra detail.

Comment: Well, it worked without the "," so if I'm looking for a [^01]$ it matches anything that does not end with 0 or 1

Comment: @manojlds - It would not match the first line since this regex requires a non-0/1 character before the end of line.

Comment: @Dan Breen Opps, yeah, missed the $, but still it wouldn't because the actual line to match ( 4) doesn't have `,`

Comment: @Christian and @manojlds are right: `,[^01]$` should not have caught line 4, although `[^01]$` (without the comma) would. So would `(?<!,[01])$`. I don't know how this could have worked as it's written.

Comment: @Justin - I don't think notepad++ supports lookarounds, unfortunately.

Comment: @Dan Breen - look at my editted response with screenshots of the entire process

Answer (score 2):

The expression you would use is

```
([^,].|,[^01])$
```

But unfortunately, notepad++ does not support alternation (the `|` operator). [1]
You can match the broken lines with these two expressions then:

```
[^,].$
,[^01]$
```

Except, of course, if the "Text" part does end in `,0` or `,1` itself. :-)

[1] http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Unsupported_Regex_Operators

Answer (score 0):

## General considerations

In general, to match a line that does not end with a specific pattern, you may use

```
^(?!.*pattern$).*$
```

where `^` matches the start of a line, `(?!.*pattern$)` is a negative lookahead that fails the match if there are 0 or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible (`.*`) followed with `pattern` at the end of the line (`$`), and the `.*$` actually matches the line.

To remove a line that does not end with some pattern together with a line break at the end, use

```
^(?!.*pattern$).*\R?
```

where `\R?` is an optional line break sequence.

In case of several fixed strings, you may use

```
^(?!.*(?:pattern|pattern2|patternN)$).*\R?
```

If there is just one or two fixed strings to check at the end of the line, you may use a bit quicker regex like

```
^.*$(?<!a)(?<!bcd)
```

that will match any line not ending with `a` and `bcd`.

```
^.*$(?<!1)(?<!0)
```

## Current problem solution

So, for the current issue, to match a line not ending with `1` or `0`, you may use

```
^(?!.*[01]$).*$    # without the line break
^(?!.*[01]$).*$\R? # with the line break
```

Or,

```
^.*(?<![01])$    # without the line break
^.*(?<![01])$\R? # with the line break
```

To remove/replace a line break on  a line that does not end with a specific pattern you may use

```
(?<![01])$\R?
```

Replace with either an empty string (to remove the line break) or with any other delimiter string or character.